# File input and output in java

Tags: java

I am beginner of java.

i am trying a write and show file.

But my txt file show another symbol.

I can not understand what my Error.

I am using this code.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            FileOutputStream output=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\BAPPY\\Desktop\\temp.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i <=10; i++) {
                output.write(i);
            }
            output.close();

            FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\BAPPY\\Desktop\\temp.txt");
            int value;
            while ((value=input.read())!=-1) {
                System.out.println(value+" ");
            }
            input.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

my txt file did not show result why please tell me??

Comment: It didn't show anything, or it had the wrong symbols? The second one is an encoding issue.

Comment: Your code works just fine. It's unclear what you're asking or what the problem actually is. I suspect you mean that *outside of your program* the txt file has symbols in it, which is the case because you're writing 11 bytes to the file that are not printable characters. Your code is converting them to numbers when you print and concat to `" "`

Comment: thanks for understanding @brianRoach.... how use concat to " " please show me code

Answer (score -1):

I think that your code is working the problem is that you are not seeing anything cause what you are writing are not understandable symbols.

Change
            for (int i = 0; i <=10; i++) {
                output.write(i);
            }

for

```
        for (int i = 66; i <=127; i++) {
            output.write(i);
        }
```

and tell how it goes.

I hope it helps

Comment: Their code is just fine, you can test it if you'd like. They are using a string concat for printing to the console after reading the byte from the file which converts it to the textual representation of the number.